# Unable to get a variable into state using setState onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

Doing a React project and keep running into a similar problem. Having trouble getting a variable into state using setState on a click. In this case i'm unable to pass my player object into state as ActivePlayer when the corresponding button gets clicked. I can however set it as a variable, but in other cases in the app I need to have it in state and this seemed like the most straightforward exampel.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import AdminSubNav from 'components/admin-subnav';
import { getPlayers } from 'api/index.js';
import { archivePlayer } from 'api/index.js';
let players = [];
let activePlayer = {};

export default class PlayerView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
          players: [],
          activePlayer: {},
          player: {}
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
          getPlayers().then((response) => {
                players = response.data;
                console.log(players);
                this.setState({ players:players });
            });
    }

    onClick(player) {
        // let activePlayer = player;
        this.setState({
            activePlayer:player
        });
        console.log(activePlayer);
        console.log(this.state);
        // archivePlayer(this.props.params.id)
        //     .then(() => {
        //         this.context.router.push('/player');
        //     });
    }

    renderPlayers() {
        return players.map((player) => {
            return (
                <tr key={player.id}>
                  <td>{player.NameLast}, {player.NameFirst}</td>
                  <td>{player.teamName}</td>
                  <td><Link to='/'><i className='material-icons small'>create</i></Link></td>
                  <td><button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, player)}><i className='material-icons small'>delete</i></button></td>
                </tr>
            );
        });
    }


  render () {

    return (
        <div>
            {/*<AdminSubNav title="Player View" route="/team/add"/>*/}
            <div className="admin-table-wrapper">
                <h3>PLAYERS</h3>
                <Link to="/player/add">ADD PLAYER</Link>
                <table className="admin-table">
                <col className="at-col1"/>
                <col className="at-col2"/>
                <col className="at-col3"/>
                <col className="at-col4"/>
                    <thead>
                         <tr>
                             <th data-field='id'>Player Name</th>
                             <th data-field='name'>Team</th>
                             <th data-field='price'>Edit</th>
                             <th data-field='price'>Archive</th>
                         </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.renderPlayers()}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The setState documentation says this,  
'setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this isn't working, or are the `console.logs` just not working? `setState` is an asynchronous function, so if you set the state and then look for it immediately after it might not be there. Try using the callback in `setState` like so:

```
this.setState({ /* state */ },() => {
   // console.log and check stuff
   // Also do any other function calls that you need to to explicitly   after the state has been updated
})
```

Not sure if this will solve it, but it's important to remember the async nature of setState!

Comment: Ahh yeah, that does log the state correctly. Thank you, you're the man!! that said, in another component where i am using a callback to setState, some components aren't rerendering the way i would think they would. I have an API that is called on componentWillMount and then an OnChange function that is called by a date picker that i want to recall the API with new data. Can componentWillMount only be called once? If so, do i just make the new API call directly in the handleChange function? Also, this should probaby be a new question with a code example eh? Thanks again either way!

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help! If you don't mind marking as accepted answer I'd appreciate it ;) And yea open up another question and post the link here as a comment and I'll go take a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
{this.renderPlayers.bind(this)()}
```

or you could also put this in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      players: [],
      activePlayer: {},
      player: {}
    }
    this.renderPlayers = this.renderPlayers.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: One of many reasons to avoid using `class`es for React components.. stick to `React.createClass({})` :)

Answer (score 0):

On your renderPlayers function, you're calling

```
players.map((player) =>
```

which will refer to the top level players Array. I would try

```
this.state.players.map((player) =>
```

in your renderPlayers function

I would also try setting your state in getInitialState on your component api

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
          players: [],
          activePlayer: {},
          player: {}
         }
}
```

Comment: `players` is a global array in this guys code, works fine :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in the onClick biding.

I was with the same problem and solved it biding the onClick handler, try this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
          players: [],
          activePlayer: {},
          player: {}
        }
       this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }
```

You can see it in the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html